# image draggable not working in parent containment

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

This example working great because here containment is body http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/hMmbK/2/

when i use container in html, it work not fine. here the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/anosim/ZXu2w/

anyone have best solution for that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What exactly is your desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you specify coordinates, they are absolute positions.

There might be a better way, but you can always get the offset of the parent and add those offsets to your containment coordinates:

```
$(function() {

    var ox = $("#container img").parent().offset().left;
    var oy = $("#container img").parent().offset().top;

    $("img").draggable({
        containment: [-99+ox, -119+oy, ox, oy],
        scroll: false
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DqdRK/

Comment: How you calculated the -99 and the -119 ?

Comment: @nmsdvid: The image width is 400x300 and the div is 300x180, for a difference of 100x120.  Then I subtracted one pixel for the width of the border.  Technically, to account for the border, it should also add to the other parameters: `containment: [-99+ox, -119+oy, ox+1, oy+1]`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're making the img tag draggable in the second fiddle. I'm assuming you want the user to be able to drag the image around the green area. Try applying draggable to the div instead. (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXu2w/1/ )

Comment: it seems I misunderstood your end goal. glad you you found a solution.